# Where can I read "Classroom of the Elite" light novel in Japanese?

Tags: resources, classroom-of-the-elite

I want to know if I can read the *Classroom of the Elite* light novel online in Japanese. Can someone share the source or web where it's available?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: @AkiTanaka agree `piracy` should not be promoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available on [BOOK☆WALKER](https://bookwalker.jp/). From their '[About](https://global.bookwalker.jp/ex/feature/about-us/#pl_qa)' page:

> BOOK☆WALKER is KADOKAWA's official bookstore and app for reading digital Manga & Light Novels worldwide.

You can just [search for it](https://bookwalker.jp/search/?qcat=&word=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D%E5%AE%9F%E5%8A%9B%E8%87%B3%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%AE%E6%95%99%E5%AE%A4%E3%81%B8) there! I don't know whether any other resources are there. But there are previews also available on BOOK☆WALKER.